# getServerSessoin returns session while useSession does not - NextJS13 with /app dir and next-auth

Tags: next.js, server, middleware, next-auth

Some notes:

- Sessions are stored in DB with next-auth.
- middleware.ts does not have access to getServerSession
- getServerSession returns a session in server components
- useSession returns nil in client components
- I am using the supabase adapter so my session strategy is 'database'

This is the session callback in authOptions:

```
async session({ session, token, user }) {
    session.user = user;
    return session;
}
```

The middleware.ts is very simple with temporarily just this:

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/profile'] // Only /profile needs authentication
};
```

I have tried switching to a JWT strategy too, setting an initial session in the sessionprovider based on SO but without succes...

Answer (score 0):

the `user` object may be `undefined` in the `session` callback, if you are using JWT strategy, you have to update the token first then update the session from it.
to do so, you have to add the JWT callback:

```js
async jwt({ user, token }) {
  if (user) {
    token.user = user;
  }
  return token
}
```

```js
async session({ session, token}) {
    session.user = token.user;
    return session;
}
```

Comment: I don't use the JWT strategy! Sorry I've explicitly mentioned it now in my post

Comment: @dejoma Is the user objecr defined in session callback ? Try to log it

Answer (score 0):

Create session provider component first

> auth-provider.ts file

```
'use client';

    import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
    
    type Props = {
        children: React.ReactNode;
    };
    
    export default function AuthProvider({ children }: Props) {
        return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
    }
```

> and wrap it in layout.ts file in main app directory like this
>
> layout.ts file

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

import AuthProvider from "./auth-provider";

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
 const session = await getServerSession();
    return (
        <AuthProvider session={session}>
            <html lang="en">
                <body className={font.className}>
                        attribute="class"
                        defaultTheme="system"
                        enableSystem
                    >
                        <main>{children}</main>
                </body>
            </html>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}
```